# Prevent multiple submissions

Tags: php, html, http-get

I have a page that sends data to itself, i.e.using `PHP_SELF`.

Upon page refresh, i.e. when the page reloads, I place two buttons - `Refresh Again`, where I 
send data using again using `PHP_SELF`. - An alert box pops up asking for confirmation, that usually occurs when date is sent again to a page.

The purpose of the second button - `Reload without sending data`,  must reload the page.

Without the above pop up box appearing, i.e. without data being sent.

Is there a way to flush out data before it is sent again to the 
server or to a page?

I send data via `$_GET`.

I check whether I receive any data as follows:

```
if(isset($_GET['getVariable']))

/* I place the buttons here, in a form, the action parameter of which points to the same page, i.e. `PHP_SELF`
```

Comment: I'd send it to an 'empty' php page which would just send it back to the previous page using `header('Location: '. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` but this makes no sense lol,

Comment: Use POST instead of GET since you are doing something with the data (other than displaying it)

Comment: That isn't something that sensitive. Hence resorted to $_GET.

Comment: Doesn't mater about sensitivity, best to be consistent and use the right type of the given job.

Comment: Also, consider using JavaScript before sending the data

Comment: How about `<input type='button' onClick='refreshPage()'>` https://forum.jquery.com/topic/onclick-goto-a-url-how

Comment: @AmazingDreams: Regd. the first case, it might not work 'as expected', when dealing with frames (Though I am not currently dealing with one). In that case, it might refresh only that frame.

Comment: What is the problem with `<input type="reset" />` http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlreset.php?

Comment: Ah! Completely missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the refresh without submitting a new form:

```
<form name="refresh" action="" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Refresh without submitting" />
</form>
```

Or use JavaScript to refresh on the current button.

```
<input type="button" value="Refresh without submitting" onclick="location.reload();" />
```

Also, use `action=""` instead of `PHP_SELF`.